# Should I revoke login from the default pgsql user?

Tags: postgresql, users, logins, root

I set up a localhost pgsql installation (os x catalina, homebrew, 12.*). I am developing a sql data warehouse and I’d like my dev environment to be as close to the production one as possible. Homebrew created a default superuser, chris. Is it ok (and possible) to revoke the login attribute from this user? I have set up dedicated users to interact with the data warehouse and the actual data in the system.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will need a superuser that can login for administrative purposes. So don't change the existing superuser to `NOLOGIN` unless you create another superuser first (but tgen you could just as well rename the existing superuser). The secure thing to do is

- use a good password for the user
- severely restrict access for that user in `pg_hba.conf`, ideally to local connections

There is one scenario where you could change the only existing superuser to `NOLOGIN`: create a regular user `admin` with `NOINHERIT` and

```
GRANT chris TO admin;
```

Then `admin` can always assume superuser privileges with

```
SET ROLE chris;
```

This setup has the advantage that you don't need a shared password for the superuser. Each administrator can have her own normal user that can assume superuser privileges when necessary.